# UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING~ EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1001)')))

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente error y no sé como resolverlo:

```
UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING~ EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1001)'))).
```

Qué significa el error?, ¿Qué debo hacer para resolverlo?, hay una tabla de códigos de error dónde consultar?

Gracias y saludos

Comment: ok pero en que momento o que interaccion ocurre el error??? una lectura de un archivo, lectura de algo en la red, consumo de algun api o algo por internet?

Comment: por que segun el error pueden ser varias cosas... un problema con el certificado ssl, configuracion del servidor o incluso hasta configuracion del firewall ... algo de lo ultimo me paso recientemente ... pero son problemas que no se resuelven por programacion... a menos que seas quien desarrolla un api de consumo...

Comment: Agrega tu código para ver donde supuestamente se esta desbordando.

Comment: Agregué el código para ver si pueden ayudarme

Comment: Será un problema de autorización de puertos?

Comment: Al código original le hice el siguiente cambio:

Comment: try:                                                                   
     requests.get("https://sfs-relay.na1-ext.cacf.kyndryl.net")         
 except requests.exceptions.SSLError as e:                              
     print(f'oops! got the following SSL error: {e}')                   
pero falló con el mismo error.

Comment: El problema se produce al probar un job, que desde un Mainframe trata de acceder un sitio donde dejaremos algunos datos que serán usados por un Dashboard. El job no es capaz de acceder al sitio, pero tampoco el job pone el mensaje de error (el código lo considera) sino es una capa anterior que aborta al job.

Comment: import requests
import urllib3
import sys
import os
############
region  = sys.argv[1]
############
urllib3.disable_warnings()

url = "https://sfs-relay."+region+"-ext.cacf.kyndryl.net"

response = requests.request("GET", url, verify=False)  
if response.status_code == 200: 
    print('Connection Stablished! Proceed to next steps for deployment')
if response.status_code != 200:
    print('Please review your firewall rules, Python not able to reach S
    print('-------- Connection response received --------')
    print(response.text)    sys.exit(10)